# Ошибка в переводе в табличке из конкурса

Tags: дефект, локализация

Ошибка в переводе на табличке под конкурсным вопросом:

> По данному вопросу был объявлен конкурс с наградой +50 баллов
>   репутации пользователем Vladimir Gamalian; конкурс закончился 23 часа назад.
>   У вас осталось **через 3 минуты** для присуждения награды.
>
> Вопросу уделили недостаточно внимания.

Скриншот:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]